# query with union, join and limit (not working)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i am stuck with a problem please Help

```
sql = mysqli_query($con, "


SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_0 
INNER JOIN komentarebi 
ON portfeli_0.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_0.user='$user'

UNION ALL 
SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_1 
INNER JOIN komentarebi 
ON portfeli_1.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_1.user='$user' 

");
```

in komentarebi i have multiple records with same person_id and i have to take only 1 of them is it possible?

Comment: This does not look like sql-server? MySQL does not equal sql-server.

Comment: It is not quite clear (to me at least) exactly what you mean when you say _limit join per 1 row (limit doesnot work)_. My initial thoughts are to try changing both your `SELECT`s to `SELECT DISTINCT`s; but without knowing more about your data...

Comment: You are getting duplicate rows? Then use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, so the duplicates are removed. If you are asking something else show us examples: some rows from both tables, the result you get and the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way limit should work

```
(SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_0 
INNER JOIN komentarebi 
ON portfeli_0.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_0.user='$user'
LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL 
(SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_1 
INNER JOIN komentarebi 
ON portfeli_1.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_1.user='$user' 
LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_0 
INNER JOIN komentarebi 
ON portfeli_0.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_0.user='$user'
LIMIT 1)

UNION 

(SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_1 
INNER JOIN komentarebi 
ON portfeli_1.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_1.user='$user' 
LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: in komentarebi i have multiple records with same person_id and i have to take only 1 of them is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicated rows, use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to remove them:

```
SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_0 INNER JOIN
     komentarebi 
     ON portfeli_0.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_0.user = '$user'

UNION 

SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM portfeli_1 INNER JOIN 
     komentarebi 
     ON portfeli_1.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
WHERE portfeli_1.user = '$user' ;
```

You can add a limit to the end of the query if you only want one row returned.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a record for the same user in both tables chances are that the postdate will be different and using UNION instead of UNION ALL won't solve the problem  (because `any difference in any of the columns` means the rows are not duplicates according the strict definition of that term, so `union` or `select distinct` does not remove them.)

So instead I propose you choose the row with that latest date:

```
SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
FROM (
    SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
    FROM portfeli_0 
    INNER JOIN komentarebi 
    ON portfeli_0.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
    WHERE portfeli_0.user='$user'

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT piadi, debtorfullName, ClientAddress, mobilePhone, principalAmount, totalAmount, status, product_name,comment ,postdate 
    FROM portfeli_1 
    INNER JOIN komentarebi 
    ON portfeli_1.piadi=komentarebi.person_id 
    WHERE portfeli_1.user='$user' 
     )
ORDER BY postdate DESC
LIMIT 1
```